# ReSharper not working in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have VS 2017 Community Edition and the latest version of ReSharper (I just love this extension), I must have done something to ruin ReSharper functions... I have reinstalled (several times) without success. Search JetBrains community for answers, all without luck so far.

Importing namespaces, code suggestion (the one I select to perform) does not get performed (unable to perform, caused by error in source code. There is no error... ) 
Intellisense is working somewhat but not quite as it should. .

Here you have a picture of import namespace (not working). Alt+Enter or mouse click does not work..

[image]

Any idea what night be causing this??

Comment: Try to clear caches (ReSharper > Options > Environment > General > Clear caches) and restart VS. If that won't help, submit a request to ReSharper support (you can easily google it).

Comment: Install VS2019, if you don't mind

Comment: You think 2019 will fix the problem??